# Deliver files from a web server from outside the web app

Tags: filesystems, tomcat, java

Is there anyway to server a file from a web server through the web, that is not within the web application.

I am using Tomcat and a Java servlets based application.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps

Answer (score 0):

If you have the web-server fronting the Tomcat install then it is quite doable, just don't serve the files from the same Location has the Tomcat instance is running. Not so sure about Java, though again, if you have a web-server fronting the servlet instead of serving directly from Java itself that kind of redirection is quite possible.